# show position mouse pointer to press CTRL key

Tags: bash, key, mouse-cursor

I'm new to bash programming, and I need ideas.
I am working on an old desktop pc (1.7 ghz cpu, 512 MB ram and 10 gb hd), with Debian 7, icewm, spacefm without any desktop environment (gnome/kde/xfce/mate, etc.), and without any GUI utilities for peripheral devices like keyboard/mouse.

I need to highlight mouse pointer position upon pressing `Ctrl`-key

The icewm window manager allows to launch a command on a keyboard event. So I need a shell script for it.

I believe that `xdotool` and `read` commands can be useful for this script, but I am not sure.

I appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate that you aren't English but i have no idea what you are asking to do.

Comment: I believe that you are trying to achieve what MS windows does when you press ctrl key (when it is enabled in accessibility settings)... ? Something similar to [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/211117-pointer-show-location-ctrl-key-enable-disable.html) windows feature...

Comment: Hello, yes, this is the I like do.

Answer (score 0):

To print the current mouse pointer coordinates, you can use the command

```
xdotool getmouselocation --shell
```